# Validating url with jQuery without the validate-plugin?

Tags: jquery, url, validation

I need to validate a url in **variable** with jQuery, but can't use validate-plugin. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use the same regex that the validation plugin does (updated to latest regex on May 23rd, 2015):

```js
function isUrlValid(url) {
    return /^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(url);
}

var testCases = [
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "ftp://www.google.com/",
    "http://google.com/",
    "http://google.com",
    "https://google.com",
    "http://www.google.com:80/",
    "https://www.google.com:443/",
    "http://127.0.0.1/",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9200/",
    "www.site.com",
    "x:",
    "http://",
    "javascript:alert('xss')",
    "http://w",
    "http:",
    "derp://www.google.com",
    "http://localserver"
],  div = document.getElementById("output");

for(var i=0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
    var test = testCases[i];
    div.innerHTML += (isUrlValid(test) ? "<span class='valid'>valid</span>:   " : "<span class='invalid'>invalid</span>: ") + "" + test + "\n";
}
```

```css
.valid { color: green; }
.invalid { color: red; }
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

This handles unicode, etc so it's a bit verbose.  Source is [the validation plugin itself](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/f37c2d8131ca0e3c2af0093f6fd9d2c40c282663/src/core.js#L1159). A few notes: it is *probably what you want*, but it is not strictly *correct*. Typically you need to choose a slightly different regex if you want to accept things like `http://w` and `http://localserver` which are valid in an intranet environment but not typically allowed in most web forms. In a way, this regex is safer because it requires a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) in such cases. Similarly other examples like custom protocols are rejected here, but are valid and do work for many things used today. If you're asking users "what's your homepage?" in a form though...you likely want to exclude these anyway.

Anyone finding this later: please feel free to test additional test cases with the snippet I included and update the answer if you feel a new common case should be mentioned. I re-wrote the answer with the latest regex and in this format to better serve the community.

Comment: Worked very well. Simple too. Would love it if you can expand the answer to show option for auto adding http:// ?

Comment: Additionally it accepts  "derp://www.google.com" as a valid url.

Comment: @user1063287 those are valid URLs, I can have a server named `w`. Only a hostname is not a valid URL.

Comment: @jnovack That is a valid URL. URLs are not constrained to only the http and https protocols. Any custom protocol is valid. This is how things like steam links and links between apps on your phone work.

Comment: I'm going to disagree on a technicality, which was the original intent of my message (sorry I was not clear). 'derp://' is a URI, not a URL.

Comment: @jnovack It is still both a valid URI and a valid URL. The RFC fo URLs (1738) specifies the syntax of schemes and *specific* schemes are enumerated (section 3 if I remember correctly) it is specifically noted **not** to be an exhaustive list. Custom protocols are allowed in URLs and are quite widely used on the internet today.

Comment: @HelpNeeder the latest regex doesn't have this issue - I improved the answer quite a bit and hopefully people can/will just add test cases when warranted...unfortunately I don't have as much time as I'd like to tend to 6,000+ answers these days :-/

Comment: @NickCraver It wont work with `*.co.in, *.co.uk and file:///` protocol.

Comment: In order to validate the FTP as a valid URL just use this `/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i`

Comment: Does this actually check if a URL goes to a 404, or does this just check for format/syntax validation?

Comment: Which part do I remove to not require any protocol `http/https/ftp/etc`?

Comment: It works fine when I paste or type the url in the input box. However, I found that it's not working on real time validate when press Backspace keyboard. Here is example: valid http://www.jinai-cl invalid http://www.jinai- and valid http://www.jinai . Any help please.

Comment: This won't work for url without any protocol like 'www.abc.com'

Comment: how to add local host in it as it is trturnin false to http://localhost/

Answer (score 35):

Thank you very much Meo and Nick, I put both your answers together and it works just great.

```
if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test($("#url").val())){
    alert("valid URL");
} else {
    alert("invalid URL");
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are sure that your audience is using HTML5, you can use `type="url"` to validate the text string.  You could also dynamically create an input element, set the type and test whether the variable is valid URL or not.

The following is based on a blog post from https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/10/19/using-html-form-validation-in-pure-javascript

```js
var elm;
function isValidURL(u){
  if(!elm){
    elm = document.createElement('input');
    elm.setAttribute('type', 'url');
  }
  elm.value = u;
  return elm.validity.valid;
}

console.log(isValidURL('http://www.google.com/'));
console.log(isValidURL('//google.com'));
console.log(isValidURL('google.com'));
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var url = $('input.surl').val();
var url_validate = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
if(!url_validate.test(url)){
   alert('error');
}
else{
   alert('success');
}
```

Comment: You should use `var` keyword before defining `url_validate` variable

Comment: You're Welcome 

Answer (score 6):

yes with a regex:

```
/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
```

Answer (score 3):

> you Want to validate your URL:
>
> Please pass the URL in this function then this will give you **true** OR **false**.
>
> See Function :

```
<script>
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}

isUrl(yourURL);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Code :

```
var re = /^(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/;
re.test('http://www.goole.in');
```

Comment: Some explanation would improve your answer. Also, question was how to validate an URL stored in a *variable*.